# How to get table name as a parameter in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
q1.table_name,
q1.column_name, 
q1.data_type, 
q1.nullable,
q2.comments 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    table_name,
    column_name,
    data_type,
    nullable
    FROM
    USER_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES'
) q1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT
    column_name,
    comments
    FROM
    USER_COL_Comments
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES'
) q2 ON q1.column_name = q2.column_name;
```

It works fine, but I need to get my table name as a parameter. And I just got stucked. How can I do this? What is the difference between function and stored procedure in Oracle? What is better to use in this case? Will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: You need to execute the query as a Dynamic Statement if the table has to be parameterised. The difference between function and stored procedure is that with function a value has to be returned explicitly using a return statement and with procedure its not required.

Comment: Function or Stored Procedure to be used, depends in your case on what you are looking to do. For example, If its just a select and writing to log file, then a procedure is fine. If there is a value to be returned to the calling method, then a function can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need subqueries here: just join the two views on table name and column name. This makes it easy to parameterise the query, because you only need populate the one instance of `table_name`.

I have used an outer join in this query because in my experience developers aren't very disciplined about writing column comments ;)

```
SELECT 
    q1.table_name,
    q1.column_name, 
    q1.data_type, 
    q1.nullable,
    q2.comments 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS q1
    left outer JOIN USER_COL_Comments q2
    ON q1.table_name = q2.table_name
    and ON q1.column_name = q2.column_name
WHERE q1.TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES'
;
```

If you need to put this in a function then it's quite straightforward: you just need to decide what return type you want. Will the function be called by other programs or used in queries? If just SQL queries, probably you should write a view instead (without the WHERE clause).

For use by programs the function should return a  ref cursor, which can be mapped to a JDBC or ODBC result set.

```
create or replace function get_table_details
     (p_table_name in user_tables.table_name%type)
     return sys_refcursor
as
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for 
    SELECT 
        q1.table_name,
        q1.column_name, 
        q1.data_type, 
        q1.nullable,
        q2.comments 
    FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS q1
        left outer JOIN USER_COL_Comments q2
        ON q1.table_name = q2.table_name
        and ON q1.column_name = q2.column_name
    WHERE q1.TABLE_NAME = p_table_name
    ;
    return rc;
end;
```

---

> "What is the difference between function and stored procedure in Oracle?"

A function returns something whereas a procedure doesn't. The convention is that a function is used for read-only features and procedures are used for changing database state. However, procedures can have OUT parameters so they can return values, and some people are ill-mannered enough to execute DML in functions. But if you stick to the convention you'll be fine.

Comment: Good explanation regarding the difference between a function and a stored procedure.